# Using C++ API in Android's WebRTC library

Tags: android, c++, webrtc

Is it possible to use the C++ WebRTC API in an Android application in a simple way?
Kind of like the Java API exposed by [these packages](https://bintray.com/google/webrtc/google-webrtc).

I'd really like to avoid having to compile everything by myself because the setup takes so long and I'd have to install Linux on my work PC since we usually work on Windows and WebRTC Android development does not support that, etc...

For context, I'd like to use WebRTC on an HTC Vive Focus and the whole VR stack (which data I need to access and send via DataChannel) is a native API. Adding JNI to that would make things needlessly complicated, so I'm looking for a way to avoid that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829837/native-android-webrtc-application-development

Comment: http://orcaman.blogspot.com/2014/07/building-native-android-webrtc-source.html

Comment: I think you have to look into [Android-Audio-Processing-Using-WebRTC](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android-Audio-Processing-Using-WebRTC)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try libdatachannel as an alternative C++ library: https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel (I'm the author)

Comment: Hi @Paul-Louis Ageneau. I've been trying to set build your library **libdatachannel** for an **Android** project. I've tried both build options you gave : [POSIX-compliant operating systems](https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel/blob/master/BUILDING.md#posix-compliant-operating-systems-including-linux-and-apple-macos) and [Build directly with Make](https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel/blob/master/BUILDING.md#build-directly-with-make-linux-only).

Comment: I, however, keep getting the following error when I try to build the project in Android Studio `C/C++: ld: error: ../../../../libs/libdatachannel/libdatachannel.a(wstransport.o) is incompatible with aarch64linux`. Would you please advise on how to get it working? How can I build it so that I get ARM builds for Android? Any way you can help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.